# How much safe a site if its not served to those who disabled Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery and Javascript extensively in my new project including form validation because I don't want to burden server using PHP validation. So I am restricting my site from the people who disabled Javascript on their browsers. I am trying to redirect them using meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=../../enablejs.html">
```

I assume that this is safe because if javascript is not enabled they will not be able to access my site.

But still I have a doubt over this and need your advice. Is it completely safe? If not what are the area I need to concetrate?

Comment: You still need PHP validation regardless

Comment: You need to concentrate on the area of server-side validaiton! Javascript validation is only good for userbility, and can easily be "hacked" to sent your server bad data

Comment: type view-source:your-url in  your browser and see what you get :)

Comment: Your site is equally vulnerable if javascript is enabled or disabled in user's browser. Safety has nothing to do with javascript disabled in user's browser. Not all of your users will have javacript disabled at a same time.

Comment: Server-side validation is mandatory. You might not know how to skip JavaScript validation but some visitor will eventually know.

Comment: And what will happen if I remove your meta tag? It's not a good idea to make validation only with JS. Client side validation is for user ease but not for security. You should validate your data on the server side.

Comment: If the only validation you have is javascript, then you basically don't have validation.  All input MUST be validated server side, or your application is potentially wide-open to attack.  Client-side validation should be treated as a usability-enhancement rather than a security feature, because it can be bypassed with ease.

Comment: If you are not going to validate data sent on the server, no matter how secure your interface is, people can bypass it by forging their own HTTP Request. Even if JavaScript is enabled, people can still view your source code then write a bookbarklet and execute it to disable your JavaScript validation.

Comment: lol, I love watching stackoverflow users implode to questions like this... Makes my day...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a terrible, terrible idea.

> because I don't want to burden server using PHP validation

You mean, you don't want to burden yourself with implementing it :)

I can relate. Everyone hates doing stuff twice. But server side validation is not a negotiable extra; client side validation can be easily circumvented and is for user convenience only. Server side validation is always needed for safety and security.

Apart from it being a bad idea, there is no way of reliably excluding  users who have JavaScript turned off. JavaScript runs on client side, and its presence or non-presence can be easily faked to the server.

Answer (score 7):

Client-side anything is ***never ever safe***. You *always* need server-side validation. It's not a "burden", it's a necessity. I don't even *need* your website to submit (unvalidated) data to your server, in the end it all just boils down to HTTP requests. If you do not validate everything the user does on the server, you have no security.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using Jquery and Javascript extensively in my new project including form validation because I don't want to burden server using PHP validation.

That shouldn't save a significant burden. It should give faster feedback to users though, which is good.

> So I am restricting my site from the people who disabled Javascript on their browsers.

That is a waste of time. The proportion of submissions in that which will be from users with JS disabled will be tiny.

> I am trying to redirect them using meta tag

That's a very user hostile thing to do.

> I assume that this is safe because if javascript is not enabled they will not be able to access my site.

If you mean that it avoids the need to write server side validation routines, then you are wrong. If someone wants to *attack* the site (rather then submit bad data by accident) then they can construct HTTP requests manually.

Answer (score 3):

No that's not safe. Client side validations are nowhere safe. With javascript enabled anyone can bypass your validations. Using chrome console I can probably alter any text on your input boxes or any other input method without you validation noticing it.

**Use server side validation or you're screwed.**

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not safe. Never rely on the browser for form validation. Form validation in the browser should only be to improve user experience, not to protect your data. You need to add some PHP validation.

Also, are people who have JavaScript disabled not supposed to use your site? You should make JavaScript degrade gracefully so that your site is still usable without it.

Answer (score 0):

Using client side validation is a recipe for disaster "never ever trust clients input" clients inputs are GET (URL included), POST, FLash ...

All inputs should be validated by server side scripting language like PHP, ASP.net, java ...
If you use PHP then check http://www.phpclasses.org/ and look for form validation scripts and Cross-site scripting (XSS). Or use validation classes offered in frameworks like zend, codeigniter

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting